# group data of multiple fields in an array

Tags: php

I have some hidden input values for each module as you see in following HTML. Once the data is posted, how can I get the data of each module in an array, so that I can store it.

```
<div class="module">Module1</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module1" name="module_id">
<input type="hidden" value="title" name="title">
<input type="hidden" value="some text" name="text">

<div class="module">Module2</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module2" name="module_id">
<input type="hidden" value="another title" name="title">
<input type="hidden" value="another text" name="text">
```

I am unable to understand how to combine the title and the text input together with their module id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `[]` after the names. PHP will turn them each into an array.

```
<div class="module">Module1</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module1" name="module_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="title" name="title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="some text" name="text[]">

<div class="module">Module2</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module2" name="module_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="another title" name="title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="another text" name="text[]">
```

Now you'll have arrays `$_POST['module_id']`, `$_POST['title']`, and `$_POST['text']` that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div class="module">Module1</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module1" name="module[0][module_id]">
<input type="hidden" value="title" name="module[0][title]">
<input type="hidden" value="some text" name="module[0][text]">

<div class="module">Module2</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module2" name="module[1][module_id]">
<input type="hidden" value="another title" name="module[1][title]">
<input type="hidden" value="another text" name="module[1][text]">

...
```

And you can access it like so:

```
foreach ($_POST['module'] as $module) {
    echo $module['module_id'];
    echo $module['title'];
    echo $module['text'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<div class="module">Module1</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module1" name="module_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="title" name="title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="some text" name="text[]">

<div class="module">Module2</div>
<input type="hidden" value="module2" name="module_id[]">
<input type="hidden" value="another title" name="title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="another text" name="text[]">
```

**To extract value use:**

```
$_POST['module_id'][0] // to access id from module 1

$_POST['module_id'][1] // to access id from module 2
```

And the same  way you can access others :)